# Django Template Error: Could not parse the remainder: ',' from 'uid,'?

Tags: django, forgot-password, django-errors

I am using Django `forgot_password` framework with custom template. I am using `Django 1.5`. My custom template `password_reset_email.html` looks like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}

#Exception:
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/password/reset/
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: ',' from 'uid,'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this in the top:

```
 {% load i18n %}{% load url from future %}
 {% autoescape off %}
 ..........
```

Remove `,`, you put it beside `uidb36=uid,`

```
 {% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
```

Comment: One more question before I accept the answer, I want password reset URL with my URL. Should I type it manually or ? Right now, instead of example.com I want it to go to 127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: No the protocol and domain right here {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}, are they stored in a database?

Comment: don't change the protocol, it's automatic, it's either http or https or whatever

Answer (score 11):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on the accepted answer, but the {% load url from future %} shouldn't be required since you're using Django 1.5. It was only needed in Django 1.3 and 1.4.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi

Comment: So the real problem in the template is the lack of quotes around the view, and the additional ',' character after uid?

Comment: Just a note to confirm Derek's answer and winwaed's comment. Fixing the quotes and removing the comment was the answer for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022 (django version 4.0.5), none of the answers here worked for me. I had to change the line:

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
```

to:

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uid token %}
```

where `password_reset_confirm` is the `name` that I have given to the *password reset confirm* view in my url pattern, which is located in the `urls.py` file insde the app where I am managing my user registration system (the app is called `users`):

```
path('pattern/<uidb64>/<token>', django.contrib.auth.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm')
```

Answer (score 0):

my issue is resolved by writing this
I'm using django 4.1

{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token  %}

Comment: Does this answer the implied *How do I get rid of Django Template Error: Could not parse the remainder: ',' from 'uid,'*? (What *has* been your issue?)